# How to add styles to a Ant Design and React App

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I am using Ant design in a Reactjs stack. I hope this question isn't too broad and is a common occurrence in similar situations.

I am having an issue overriding some of the CSS. I want to modify the .ant-layout-header class so that it uses less padding. I found the style I need to modify in the antd.css
@import '../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css';

I change it from

```
padding: 0 50px;
```

to

```
padding: 0 25px;
```

When I look at the code in my browser after my save it appears as though nothing changes. I found my change is now in its own  tag and looks like:

```
.Dashboard__ant-layout-header___3h1_L
```

'.Dashboard__' is added at the beginning and '___3h1_L' to the end of it.

At this point, I don't fully understand why this occurring. Has anyone seen this type of thing happen? If so how do I make a change that to existing CSS without getting these extra classes?

Comment: Please make some sandbox (codesandbox.io), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). CSS problems usually solved quickly with a playground

Comment: First of all, this not the right way to import the CSS file to the component, secondary it's a  not good practice to edit antd style instead create your own custom CSS for the whole app or for each component the override what you looking for.